# Targeting product terms from a custom taxonomy in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I use some custom taxonomies in my website… **`movies_type`** *(is one of them)* and has 4 terms:

- **`movie`**,
- **`tvseries`**,
- **`concert-and-ceremony,`**
- **`documentary`**

I have tagged Every product with just one of this terms.

How can I target those products that have the same term?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**has_term()**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) WordPress function **to target your products** with terms **from a custom taxonomy**, just as for **product categories** which custom taxonomy is "product_cat"

For example, you can use it this way:

```
if ( has_term( 'movie', 'movies_type' ) ) {
    // Do something
} elseif ( has_term( 'tvseries', 'movies_type' ) ) {
    // Do another thing
}
```

This should work for you…

---

For **product categories** you will use `'product_cat'` custom taxonomy:

```
if ( has_term( 'clothing', `'product_cat'` ) ) {
    // Do something
}
```

For **Product tags** you will use `'product_tag'` custom taxonomy:

```
if ( has_term( 'books', 'product_tag' ) ) {
    // Do something
}
```