# Change the add to cart text for a specific product category in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I want to change the add to cart text on product archives on **specific categories** only. For example, on **preorder category** i want instead of `add to cart` text, to be `Preorder`. I don't know how to **identify Preorder category** in the below function.

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // < 2.1

function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

        return __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Update:** `add_to_cart_text` hook is obsolete & deprecated. It is  replaced in Woocommerce 3+ by `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` filter hook.

It can be 2 different things *(as your question is not so clear)*…

1) To target products **on a specific product category archive pages** you should use the conditional function [**`is_product_category()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'product_cat_add_to_cart_button_text', 20, 1 );
function product_cat_add_to_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    // Only for a specific product category archive pages
    if( is_product_category( array('preorder') ) )
        $text = __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );

    return $text;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

---

2) To target a specific product category on Woocommerce archives pages you will use [**`has term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'product_cat_add_to_cart_button_text', 20, 1 );
function product_cat_add_to_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    // Only for a specific product category
    if( has_term( array('preorder'), 'product_cat' ) )
        $text = __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );

    return $text;
}
```

For single product pages you will use additionally this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'product_cat_single_add_to_cart_button_text', 20, 1 );
function product_cat_single_add_to_cart_button_text( $text ) {
    // Only for a specific product category
    if( has_term( array('preorder'), 'product_cat' ) )
        $text = __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );

    return $text;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> **Note:** All filter hooked functions needs to return the main argument if you set some conditions, so in this case the argument `$text`…

---

Related answer: [Targeting product terms from a custom taxonomy in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327002/targeting-product-terms-from-a-custom-taxonomy-in-woocommerce/39327073#39327073)

Related docs: [Woocommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [has_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) with condition. Updated code is as below.

**Solution- 1. Using filter `add_to_cart_text`**

```
 add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );   

    function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

            global $product;

             if(has_term('your-special-category', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())){
              $text = __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );
             }
              return $text;
    }
```

**Solution- 2. Using filter `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text`**

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );   

    function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {

            global $product;

             if(has_term('your-special-category', 'product_cat', $product->get_id())){
              $text = __( 'Preorder', 'woocommerce' );
             }
              return $text;
    }
```

where `your-special-category` will your category for which you want to replace `add to cart` text.

Comment: If `add_to_cart_text` is not working (as it is old filter) , you can use another filter `woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text` . I have updated my answer.