# Add to Cart button replacement for specific category in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, product

I tried using *[Change the add to cart text for a specific product category in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354487/change-the-add-to-cart-text-for-a-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce-3/48354999#48354999)* answer code *(3rd function)* to change the text and link for the Add to Cart button on a specific category on Woocommerce site.

I have just make this change to the code *(for the required product category)*:

```
if( has_term( array('evoheat-heat-pumps'), 'product_cat' ) )
```

But what I need is to display a custom text "Contact" and also redirect to specific url like `https://www.example.com/contact-us/` when this button is clicked.

But so far I have only been able to change the text.

How to replace Add to Cart button for specific product category in WooCommerce?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead that will replace add to cart button by a custom linked button for specific product categories:

```
// Replacing the loop add to cart button by a custom button for specific product category
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_loop_add_to_cart_link_callback', 10, 2 );
function filter_loop_add_to_cart_link_callback( $button, $product  ) {
    $terms = array('evoheat-heat-pumps'); // Here your product categories ( Ids, slugs or names )

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){
        $button = contact_us_replacement_button();
    }

    return $button;
}

// Replacing the single product  add to cart button for a specific product category
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_single_product_summary_callback', 1 );
function action_single_product_summary_callback() {
    global $product;

    $terms = array('evoheat-heat-pumps'); // Here your product categories ( Ids, slugs or names )

    if( has_term( $terms, 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ){

        // For variable product types
        if( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'contact_us_replacement_button', 20 );
        }
        // For all other product types
        else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'contact_us_replacement_button', 30 );
        }
    }
}

// The button "Contact us" replacement button function
function contact_us_replacement_button(){
    $href = home_url('/contact-us/'); // The link
    $text = __( "Contact us", "woocommerce" );

    // Output button
    echo '<a class="button" href="'.$href.'">' . $text . '</a>';
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't quite work. This has changed the button to Contact as it should, but when pressed, it still adds to cart and then transforms into a slightly different styled Contact button which when pressed for the second time takes you to the Contact URL.

Comment: @seangolding1987 Sorry but this is not possible… You have just forgot to remove some other custom code or there is a plugin that is making trouble (or even it can be your theme customizations). The replacement button is a simple button that can't add anything to cart and when pressed it goes to "contact-us"… For the styling, you can add any related class or/and add some custom CSS rules. This is tested and works on last woocommerce version under storefront theme.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec , thank you so much for your help. It was a caching issue that was causing the problem. Deleted the cache and now works great! Thanks again!